# If certain div has css value than show other divs

Tags: javascript, php

I am looking for a way to display further divs if a certain CSS value of a class is available. Maybe this is possible whit some javascript. But i dont know how i can output php on JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementByClass('visible-only-if-sent').style.display = 'block';) { 

//so some php///

</srcipt>
```

any ideas? 
maybe it is also a possibility to use a php loop and a statement js?

edit: I want to show this code (below) only when the class visible-only-if-sent has the value display:block;

```
<?php if( have_rows('social_media', 19) ):
while ( have_rows('social_media', 19) ) : the_row();

    // vars
        $background_social_media = get_sub_field('background_social_media', 19);
        $slogan_social_media = get_sub_field('slogan_social_media', 19);
        $social_icon1 = get_sub_field('social_icon1',19);
        $social_icon2 = get_sub_field('social_icon2', 19);
        $social_icon3 = get_sub_field('social_icon3', 19);
        $social_icon4 = get_sub_field('social_icon4', 19);



        ?>
<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Comment: You would need to use AJAX to interact with PHP

Comment: why not use jQuery for style properties?

Comment: Perhaps if you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve, then we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is a server-side language, it compiled and rendered as HTML in the browser, that's because if you see the page source you don't see any PHP tags or code.

there're two solutions here:

---

**use ajax to get content from server**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       if ($('.visible-only-if-sent').is(':visible')) { 
       {
          $('#newContent').load('/News/GetLatest/10'); // call ajax to get content
       }

</script>

   <div id="newContent"></div>
```

---

**or you can only show the div if condition is true on the client side** 
**PHP Page** index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var showContent = false;

       if ($('.visible-only-if-sent').is(':visible')) { 
       {
          showContent = true;
          $('#newContent').show(); // show it
       }

</script>

   <div id="newContent" style="display: none;"> <!-- hidden by default -->
      <?php echo ' any content here '; ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. What i have to do with this line: var showContent = @myVariable; // false ? the rest seems to be clear.

Comment: also i see open two brackets and close only one?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, this line should be *false* and remove @myVariable ... and where is the two brackets opened?

Comment: after the if statement you open two brackts and only one is closed after after the comment //show it